# Caffe: make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.o] Error 1

Tags: caffe

When I make caffe in ubuntu16.04, I get this error:

```
CXX src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.cpp
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:2187:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/bind.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind_mf_cc.hpp:52:6: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘:>’ token
     >:>type BOOST_BIND(R (BOOST_BIND_MF_CC T::*f) () const BOOST_BIND_MF_NOEXCEPT, A1 a1)
      ^
Makefile:584: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.o] Error 1
```

Does somebody know how to fix it ? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of `g++` are you using? Ensure that it's atleast version `4.8`

I suggest you to install `g++-4.8` and selecting it in Makefile.config `(CUSTOM_CXX :=g++-4.8)` then compiling again.

Also ensure that you're using appropriate version of `boost` lib for given version of `g++` that you're using.

Comment: my g++ is 5.4. The last time it can make will.but this time I make clean and remake my caffe, then I get this error.

Comment: I also change gcc to 4.7 ,but it still has this problem.

Comment: @Frank.Fan Just check whether you've multiple versions of gcc being installed and which one is being used? Note that g++ 4.7 does not handle C++11 well and error indicates this could be the case.